# How to deal with a key being pressed all the time, and interfering with mouse functionality, after I spilled liquid on the keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard

After having spilled a liquid on the keyboard of my laptop, began to register several keys as “pressed” when they weren’t. I disassembled the keyboard and deeply cleaned it and managed to make it work again, but with the exception that the <kbd>7</kbd> key kept on being pressed all the time. I had to install a program to deactivate keys and manage to deactivate the  <kbd>7</kbd> key.

So far so good, until I noticed that sometimes when I click the mouse it does not detect it and I have to click it several times and there it works. I have tried other mice and that is not the problem.

Then I installed a program that detects the keystrokes of the keyboard and the mouse to see if it detects any other key that is being pressed and the following appears:

> “LButton, OemClear”

Are pressed at all times and that makes it difficult to use my external mouse.

I have searched the Internet for the keys with those values ​​and I can not find anything about them. Can anyone provide any insight?

This is the program in operation where it is observed that it is detecting those 2 pulsations:

> [image]

This is the program I use to deactivate the key number Seven but this one in its list of keys does not have any with the values: “LButton and OemClear”:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

For the $30 to $50 expense of replacing the keyboard, you are better off just replacing it.  If you give it a drink or pop the scissor lift under a key, it isn't economical to mess with in a repair shop environment.

With corrosion, unless you get every bit cleaned up and removed, it will regrow with current.